# How to successfully connect to my local MySQL 8.0 database from my Spring Boot application pushed to my local PCF DEV?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pcfdev

My app ([gs-spring-boot.zip](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-sample-app-spring/files/3623897/gs-spring-boot.zip)) is unable to connect to the locally running MySQL 8.0 database after carrying out the following configurations as described in various tutorials online.

Please find the errors in the attached log file named [cf_spring_boot_log.txt](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-sample-app-spring/files/3614640/cf_spring_boot_log.txt)

Please find a screenshot of the MySQL account with same credentials as configured below.

[Local MySQL account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK1IQ.jpg)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cf login -a https://api.dev.cfdev.sh --skip-ssl-validation -u admin -p admin

PS E:\> cf cups mysql80-db -p '{\"username\": \"pcf\", \"password\": \"pcfpassword\", \"name\": \"world\", \"hostname\": \"127.0.0.1\", \"port\": 3306, \"uri\": \"mysql://pcf:pcfpassword@127.0.0.1:3306/world\", \"jdbcUrl\": \"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/world?user=pcf&password=pcfpassword\"}'

PS E:\> cf push pcf-people-mgmt -p C:\Users\ranadeep-sharma\IdeaProjects\gs-spring-boot\complete\target\pcf-people-mgmt-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

PS E:\> cf bind-service pcf-people-mgmt mysql80-db

PS E:\> cf restage pcf-people-mgmt
```

I have spent weeks with no success. **Please let me know what I am missing in my configuration.**

Comment: Gentle Reminder: Are you sure there is no sensitive information in that attachment? Doesn't look like that. Better please remove it.

Comment: The password in my uploads is a dummy one. Should not be a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, after using correct IP Address.